# ScrollView Not Scrolling in small view height in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on a react native project but my scrollView is not working on small View height.
This is my code.

```
<View style={{height: 300}}>
    <ScrollView>
        <View>
            ...
        </View>
        <View>
            ...
        </View>
        ...
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Please what could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

I have added more styling to explain further... The scrollView is in a bottom sheet `react-native-raw-bottom-sheet` which is the RBSheet as seen in the code. The scrollView isn't scrolling. Is anything wrong?

```
    <View>
      <RBSheet
        ref={ref}
        closeOnDragDown={true}
        closeOnPressMask={true}
        height={500}
        customStyles={{
          draggableIcon: {
            backgroundColor: Colors.light,
          },
          container: {
            borderTopLeftRadius: 16,
            borderTopRightRadius: 16,
          },
        }}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <View style={{padding: 16}}>
                <View style={{height:300}}>
                  <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}>
                    <View
                      style={[
                        FlexDirections.row,
                        JustifyContent.spaceBetween,
                        {paddingVertical: 8},
                      ]}>
                      <Text style={FontWeight.bold}>Name</Text>
                      <Text>Jane doe</Text>
                    </View>
                    ...

                  </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
      </RBSheet>
    </View>
```

Comment: It should work, can you show your entire render ? (+ style)

Comment: @CR7 i have updated the question to show some more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set closeOnDragDown to false.

If you need closeOnDragDown to be true, what you can try is to add an TouchableOpacity directly after the  ScrollView like this:

```
   <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}>
      <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1}>
        <View
          style={[
            FlexDirections.row,
            JustifyContent.spaceBetween,
            { paddingVertical: 8 },
          ]}>
          <Text style={FontWeight.bold}>Name</Text>
          <Text>Jane doe</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </ScrollView>
```